# DHTMLX : Known problems with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, dhtmlx

Are there any DHTMLX users out there?

We have an app that is being developed that renders fine in Firefox and Chrome, but is suffering greatly under IE.  Any thoughts?

Copied from IE detailed error diaglog box:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729) Timestamp: Thu, 29 Oct 2009 20:16:33 UTC
>
> Message: 'rows[...].id' is null or not
>   an object Line: 665 Char: 156 Code: 0
>   URI:
>   http://xxx.xxx.com/coreLib/dhtmlx/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js
>
> Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to
>   modify the parent container element
>   before the child element is closed
>   (KB927917) Line: 0 Char: 0 Code: 0
>   URI:
>   http://xxx.xxx.com/dd/medentry/accession/edit/9093368657

TIA

Comment: Take a look at the myriad other questions involving KB927917: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=KB927917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ultimate solution for this problem - run js code from onload event. In case of dhtmlx toolkit it can be organized as

```
dhtmlxEvent(window, "load", function(){
     ... place components initialization here ...
})
```

Comment: I apologize for the late recognition.  It's taken me a while to get back to this particular problem.  While not the full solution, this put us in position to solve the end problem quicker. Thanks.